# div in headline tag autocloses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this HTML-Content. I knew that this is not correct HTML but I can't change it because it's user generated by a WYSIWG-Editor and this mistake was done hundered of times by users:

```
<div>
  <H2 style="COLOR: #0000ff"> <DIV align=left>TEXT<br /></H2></STRONG>
  </DIV>
</div><br />
```

Problem is that the Div AFTER the H2 Tag is closed AFTER the closing Tag from the H2.

What happens is that the H2 autocloses the enclosed DIV and the original  closes the Div above.

As I can't change the Sourcecode in those masses of Content-Files, is there a way to prevent this behaviour with CSS???

Comment: wafff your *WYSIWG-Editor* sucks ... you can't do anything with CSS for that it stills been invalid html

Comment: WYSIWIG-editor will generate stuff that you will never want, so there is nothing to do. I don't know why CSS could help you...?

Comment: I knew that the WYSIWG-Editor really sucks, but this content just existst :-( I tried to force H2 and/or DIV with display:inline, but this won't help as the H2 hard closes excapsulted DIV Tag and the closing Tag is double then...

Comment: Sorry dude, but I think you might be screwed. You probably need to go in and correct every content-file.

Comment: You can't fix broken `HTML` markup with `CSS`, you need to fix the underlying problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS won't fix this.  If this is generated by the editor specifically then you need a new editor.  If you're setting content in JavaScript based on the content of an editable region you might be in luck.  Browsers auto-close tags as the content is assigned.  Say you have JavaScript to handle that content, and you're assigning that HTML to an element.  When it's assigned to the element it will add the closing tag, and then when you go to programmatically close the tag at the correct time you'll get the duplicate close.  I found when I do this I need to store the HTML into a string var temporarily, and then assign the HTML when it's all complete.  If you need a quick lightweight html5 editor I have one at http://www.makrit.net/5edit